# auto_ptr or shared_ptr equivalent in managed C++/CLI classes

Tags: c++-cli, smart-pointers, auto-ptr

In C++/CLI , you can use native types in a managed class by it is not allowed to hold a member of a native class in a managed class : you need to use pointers in that case.

Here is an example :

```
class NativeClass
{
....
};


public ref class ManagedClass
{
private:
  NativeClass mNativeClass; // Not allowed !

  NativeClass * mNativeClass; // OK

  auto_ptr<NativeClass> mNativeClass; //Not allowed !
  boost::shared_ptr<NativeClass> mNativeClass; //Not allowed !

};
```

Does anyone know of an equivalent of shared_ptr in the C++/CLI world?

Edit:
Thanks for your suggestion, "1800-Information". Following your suggestion, I checked about STL.Net but it is only available with Visual Studio 2008, and it provides containers + algorithms, but no smart pointers.

Comment: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/1695/scoped-ptr-for-c-cli-ensure-managed-object-properly-frees-owned-native-object

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer on [codeproject](http://www.codeproject.com) :

Nishant Sivakumar posted an article about this at http://www.codeproject.com/KB/mcpp/CAutoNativePtr.aspx

On this page, also look for the comment by Denis N. Shevchenko : he provides a stl-like implementation that works quite well.

Comment: please avoid links, they could get broken

Answer (score 2):

I haven't thoroughly tested this but how about something like the following:

```
#pragma once

#include <memory>

template <class T>
public ref class m_shared_ptr sealed
{
    std::shared_ptr<T>* pPtr;

public:
    m_shared_ptr() 
        : pPtr(nullptr) 
    {}

    m_shared_ptr(T* t) {
        pPtr = new std::shared_ptr<T>(t);
    }

    m_shared_ptr(std::shared_ptr<T> t) {
        pPtr = new std::shared_ptr<T>(t);
    }

    m_shared_ptr(const m_shared_ptr<T>% t) {
        pPtr = new std::shared_ptr<T>(*t.pPtr);
    }

    !m_shared_ptr() {
        delete pPtr;
    }

    ~m_shared_ptr() {
    delete pPtr;
    }

    operator std::shared_ptr<T>() {
        return *pPtr;
    }

    m_shared_ptr<T>% operator=(T* ptr) {
        pPtr = new std::shared_ptr<T>(ptr);
        return *this;
    }

    T* operator->() {
        return (*pPtr).get();
    }
};
```

This should let you use C++11/Boost's shared_ptrs interchangebly in ref classes.

Answer (score 0):

[STL.Net is documented here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms379600.aspx). I don't know what state it is in or what use it might be for you.

Answer (score 0):

For those who come here and looking for a managed `auto_ptr`:

```
#include <msclr/auto_gcroot.h>

...
{
  msclr::auto_gcroot<ManagedType^> item(gcnew ManagedType());
  ...
}
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/dotnet/auto-gcroot-class