# Retrieve native object from CLI wrapper

Tags: c++, c++-cli

I have some native objects which interacts each other.
Now, I wrapped some of these objects into a managed classes. But there are some cases in which I have to retrieve the native wrapped object.

For example, take the following objects:

This is a native class which creates Sessions objects.

```
private class SessionFactory : public ISessionFactory {
  public:
    ~SessionFactory() {};
    SessionFactory(MessageEventHandler* handler) : m_handler(handler) {};

    /// Creates an instance of a Session,
    /// using the given message handler.
    inline Session* createSession(const IMessageDispatcher* dispatcher) {
      Session* s = new Session(dispatcher);
      s->AddMsgHandler( m_handler );
      return s;
    };

  private:
    MessageEventHandler* m_handler;
};
```

This is a managed class which wrap the native MessageEventHandler object.

```
public ref class NetMessageEventHandler {
  public:      
    NetMessageEventHandler() {
      m_NativeHandlerPtr = new MessageEventHandler();
    }

    const MessageEventHandler* GetNativeObject() const;

  private:
    MessageEventHandler* m_NativeHandlerPtr;
};
```

Now, into the following NetMessageDispatcher I have to interact with each of the previous:

```
public ref class NetMessageDispatcher {
  public:
    NetMessageDispatcher(MessageEventHandler^ handler) {
      m_Dispatcher = new MessageDispatcher( new SessionFactory(handler->GetNativeObject()) );
    }

  private:
    MessageDispatcher* m_Dispatcher;
}
```

Is this approach correct or there are some other best practices?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The basic principle is ok: if you need the native object you'll have to expose it, simple as that. There's no problem returning it as you do, after all C++\CLI was designed to make things like this possible.

Eventually you could move the responsability of creating the MessageDispatcher out of the managed NetMessageDispatcher: NetMessageDispatcher know needs to know how to create a MessageDispatcher from a MessageEventHandler so that's an extra dependency that's not necessarty. It's probably better to just pass it a MessageDispatcher in the constructor directly.

Also take care not to introduce memory leaks here, you have a lot of new but no delete. Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/176403/auto-ptr-or-shared-ptr-equivalent-in-managed-c-cli-classes) for example and use standard smart pointers in your native classes.

Comment: Hi @stijn, thanks for the reply! The MessageDispatcher is a native object wrapped by NetMessageDispatcher so, maybe, is not the case to pass it in the ctor. For the "delete", yes, here I write only a subset of my code for clarity :-)