# c++/cli wrapper for variable of native smart-pointer class

Tags: c++-cli, clr, wrapper

I'm new to C# and C++/CLI and not quite familiar with them. I searched but couldn't find an existing solution for a pretty simple thing (which I suppose should be common).

I am writing a simple C++/CLI project (a wrapper to C++ native dlls to be used in C#). There are many examples how to write a wrapper for native class:

```
class CNativeClass { 
    CNativeClass() {}
    void Foo() {}
}

public ref class CNativeClassWrapper {
public:
    CNativeClassWrapper() {
        _Wrapper = new CNativeClass;
    }
    ~CNativeClassWrapper() {
        this->!CNativeClassWrapper();
    }
    !CNativeClassWrapper() {
        delete _Wrapper;
        _Wrapper = nullptr;            
    }
    void Foo() {
        _Wrapper->Foo();
    }
private:
    CNativeClass* _Wrapper;
}
```

This is simlified example code. There may be more native classes, there may be late initialization... A lot minor but necessary code.

Is there any *wrapper for variable* of native class which hides all these details?
Like smart pointer templates in pure C++.

Moreover,
if a native class is actually a smart pointer (90% of my cases, we use boost::shared_ptr<>) the code becomes a mess:

- check can be `if ( _Wrapper )` or `if ( *_Wrapper )` or even `if ( _Wrapper && *_Wrapper )`,
- access to methods `(*_Wrapper)->Foo();`,
- how to reset? both `(*_Wrapper).reset();` and `_Wrapper->reset();` are correct but it is too confusing.

Does anybody know a solution for this?

Comment: Smart pointers are about as useful as a chocolate teapot in interop.  The wrapper code is very boilerplate, you can auto-generate it with a tool like swig.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I have finally come to such wrapper classes:

- for holding general native classes:

  ```
  template <class T>
  public ref class native_auto_ptr
  {
  public:
      native_auto_ptr()
      {
          _pNative = new T;
      }
      native_auto_ptr(const native_auto_ptr<T>% rhs)
      {
          _pNative = new T( *rhs._pNative );
      }
      ~native_auto_ptr()
      {
          reset();
      }
      void reset()
      {
          delete _pNative;
          _pNative = nullptr;
      }
      T* ptr()
      {
          return _pNative;
      }
      T* operator->()
      {
          return _pNative;
      }
      operator bool()
      {
          return _pNative;
      }
      void operator=(const native_auto_ptr<T>% rhs)
      {
          *_pNative = *rhs._pNative;
      }
      void operator=(const T% rhs)
      {
          *_pNative = rhs;
      }
  protected:
      !native_auto_ptr()
      {
          reset();
      }
  private:
      T* _pNative;
  };
  ```
- for holding `shared_ptr<>`:

  ```
  template <class T>
  public ref class native_shared_ptr
  {
  public:
      native_shared_ptr()
      {
          _spNative = new boost::shared_ptr<T>;
      }
      native_shared_ptr(const native_shared_ptr<T>% rhs)
      {
          _spNative = new boost::shared_ptr<T>;
          *this = rhs;
      }
      native_shared_ptr(const boost::shared_ptr<T>% rhs)
      {
          _spNative = new boost::shared_ptr<T>( rhs );
      }
      ~native_shared_ptr()
      {
          reset();
      }
      void reset()
      {
          delete _spNative;
          _spNative = nullptr;
      }
      T* operator->()
      {
          return _spNative->get();
      }
      operator bool()
      {
          return _spNative && *_spNative;
      }
      void operator=(const native_shared_ptr<T>% rhs)
      {
          *_spNative = *rhs._spNative;
      }
      void operator=(const boost::shared_ptr<T>% rhs)
      {
          *_spNative = rhs;
      }
  protected:
      !native_shared_ptr()
      {
          reset();
      }
  private:
      boost::shared_ptr<T>* _spNative;
  };
  ```

I am quite happy :)

- They hide new/delete jobs.
- They are safe.
- Their syntax is close to common smart-pointer, which is convenient.

The only issue is with the ctors with parameters... (TBD)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a build-in class shipped with the C++/CLI framework, but you can easily design your own.

Take a look at this question: [auto_ptr or shared_ptr equivalent in managed C++/CLI classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/176403/auto-ptr-or-shared-ptr-equivalent-in-managed-c-cli-classes)

I would not use smart pointers. The managed wrapper to the native object will take care of releasing the native object when the containing managed class is disposed or finalized.